# VB can't get the right function to work with strings

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vba

Basically, I'm trying to do some string manipulation to edit directories.
I found some code to try and edit the directories, but when I use it it doesn't recognise 'right' as being a function and only recognises it as a right property, thus producing an error.

I was wondering if there's something I haven't imported or if perhaps 'right' is an obsolete function that was used in VB6 but replaced with something.

The code I have is as follows:

```
Dim Foo As String
Dim Bar As String
Bar = 'some form of directory input i.e. my.computer.currentdirectory
Foo = right(Bar, (Len(Bar) - InStrRev(Bar, "/")))
MsgBox(Foo)
```

Ideally I need either a better method of manipulating directories or a way to get the 'right' functionality working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look up System.IO.Path - has lots of useful tools for this stuff.  You'll want GetDirectoryName and GetFileName especially. They work on directories as well as filenames.

```
Bar = "C:\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3"
Foo = IO.Path.GetFileName(Bar)  'now = Dir3
Foo = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Bar)  'now = C:\Dir1\Dir2
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname

Comment: Thank you for the info. I've used IO before for streamwriters/readers, but I didn't think it would have a function like that.
Thanks as well for the coherency of your answer, it made things very clear and I expect your code is probably very readable compared to a lot of programmer's spaghetti.

Answer (score 6):

> but when I use it it doesn't recognise 'right' as being a function and only recognises it as a right property, thus producing an error.

If you have a "right" property, you can fully qualify the function:

```
Foo = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(Bar, (Len(Bar) - InStrRev(Bar, "/")))
```

For details, see the docs for the [Right Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dxs6hz0a%28v=vs.80%29).

Note that, for directory parsing, you can handle this much more cleanly via the `System.IO` namespace.  In particular, you can construct a [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) and get the parent folder via the [Parent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.parent.aspx) property.

You can also use [Path.GetDirectoryName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx) to work with strings.  In your case, if you had `Bar` set to "C:\Some\Path\To\A\File.txt" and you call `Path.GetDirectoryName(Bar)`, it will return "C:\Some\Path\To\A".  If you call it on that, you'll get ""C:\Some\Path\To", etc.

Comment: There wasn't a right property as I was using a self-made class with at the time only subroutines, it turns out that while I was expecting right to be a function of a string as I thought that would be more logical than it being a standard function.

Thanks for the assistance though, both methods suggested will come in helpful for what I am working on.